# Hide node in SKScene in interface builder

Tags: swift, interface-builder, skscene, sknode

I have several SKScene done in interface builder in which I have positioned several sprites within the part of the SKScene that is visible on the screen

I want some sprites to only appear later so I start to hide them at the beginning in the didMoveToView method.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
        // Reading of the sprites created in the SKScene in the interface builder
    BackgroundLayer = self.childNodeWithName("BackgroundLayer") as! SKSpriteNode
    LettreB = self.childNodeWithName("B0") as! SKSpriteNode
    LettreB.hidden = true
    LettreR = self.childNodeWithName("R0") as! SKSpriteNode
    LettreR.hidden = true
    LettreI = self.childNodeWithName("I0") as! SKSpriteNode
    LettreI.hidden = true
}
```

The issue I have is that when running the app I very briefly see all sprites before they are hidden.

Even if I set the blendfactor to 1 (and blendmode to Alpha) in interface builder, the sprites - that are then not visible anymore in the interface builder - very briefly appear then disappear when running the app

Is there a way to avoid that except by putting the sprites outside of the visible area and moving them when I need them to appear ? Should I put the code above somewhere else before didMoveToView is called ?

Note : this issue only happens when running the app directly from the device, not when the app is launch through Xcode, for some performance reasons I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually using uppercase to the properties name it's considered as a bad attitude, you should use backgroundLayer or lettreB

This kind of changes can be do it in different ways (during the `SKScene` init methods, or by customizing your `SKSpriteNode` and change his inits), one of them is in the previous `SKScene` or `UIViewController` where you create the scene and call it:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("---")
        print("∙ \(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType))")
        print("---")
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        if let scene = MyScene(fileNamed:"MyScene") {
           var letter = scene.childNodeWithName("LettreB") as! SKSpriteNode //for example
           letter.hidden = true //for example
           skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right directions. I'll try during SKScene init which seems a good approach.